# Square Root Inequality with param

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

I don't understand, what should I do to solve?

[image]

Do I need to make a replacement in the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to suppose $a^2-x^2\ge0$ and $2x\ge0$ so 
\begin{equation}
0 \le x\le \lvert a \rvert
\end{equation} After you can put the square root at the right side
$$2x>\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$
that it means:
$$4x^2>a^2-x^2.$$
This is equivalent to
$$x^2>\frac{a^2}{5}.$$
That it means $$x<-\frac{\lvert a \rvert}{\sqrt 5} \quad \mbox{and} \quad x>\frac{\lvert a \rvert}{\sqrt 5}$$
Now, considering the before statement we have:

$$\frac{\lvert a \rvert}{\sqrt 5} < x \le \lvert a \rvert $$

Comment: Can you tell me why you are writing: x<-|a|/sqrt(5) ? I vote for your answer. But I really do not understand why you mention this?

Comment: The solution of $x^2>\frac{a^2}{5}$ is $x<-\frac{\lvert a \rvert}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $x>\frac{\lvert a \rvert}{\sqrt{5}}$. It's  a second order disequation. But you have to intersecate this solution with $0<x<\lvert a \rvert$. So you obtain the final result that i wrote above.

Comment: If I have a $ x^2>\frac{a^2}{5} $, I think $\sqrt{a^2}$ is just $|a|$. How can I get $-|a|$ ? If $a$ is negative, for example $-2$, $\sqrt{(-2)^2} = 2$. Do I have mistakes?

Comment: No you're not but, if you have $x^2=\frac{a^2}{5}$ it means that $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{5}}=\pm \frac{\lvert a \rvert}{\sqrt{5}}$. So for rules of 
 quadratic inequality you obtain the I wrote above. Please check the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

$$0\le\sqrt{a^2-x^2}<2x\to \\a^2-x^2<4x^2\to 5x^2>a^2\to\\x>\dfrac{|a|}{\sqrt 5}\\or\\x<-\dfrac{|a|}{\sqrt 5}$$since because of $0\le\sqrt{a^2-x^2}<2x$ we have $x>0$ then $x<-\dfrac{|a|}{\sqrt 5}$ is invalid therefore:$$\dfrac{|a|}{\sqrt 5}<x\le |a|$$

Comment: But it's not exact! If i put $a=0$ the problem is impossible.

Comment: Thank you I corrected it!

Comment: I think is always wrong. You have to considerer $a^2-x^2 \ge 0$

Comment: Cool feedbacks!

Answer (score 1):

If $a=0$ we have $2x>\sqrt{-x^2},$ which has no solutions.

Let $a\neq0$.

Thus, the domain gives $$a^2-x^2\geq0$$ or $$-|a|\leq x\leq|a|.$$

Since $$2x>\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\geq0,$$ we obtain $x>0$, which gives $$0<x\leq|a|.$$

Now, squaring gives $$4x^2>a^2-x^2$$ or
$$x^2>\frac{a^2}{5},$$ which with domain gives
$$\frac{|a|}{\sqrt5}<x\leq|a|.$$

We got the answer:

If $a=0$ then $\varnothing$;

If $a\neq0$ then $\left(\frac{|a|}{\sqrt5},|a|\right]$.